# SwiftUI With Local Notification Action

Tags: swift, swiftui, localnotification

I use these tow classes to manage the local notifications in the app, the problem is when I tap the notification action button "Mark as Completed" its didn't make the action its just take me to the app, so how I can make the notification action button respond to the action?

The Notification Manager Class

```
    internal final class LocalNotificationManager {
        
        private static let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
        // MARK: Ask for permission
        static func askUserPermissionToSendNotifications() {
            self.center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
                if success {
                   // Do something if user allowing notifications
                } else if !success {
                    // Do something if user do not allow the notifications
                } else if let error = error {
                    // Show some message
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        
        // MARK: Schedul Notification
        static func schedulNotification(for taskModel: TaskModel) {
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.interruptionLevel = .timeSensitive
            content.body = taskModel.text
            content.subtitle = "\(taskModel.priority != .none ? "\(taskModel.priority.rawValue) Priority" : "")"
            content.categoryIdentifier = "Task Actions" // Same Identifier in registerCategories()
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            let taskIdentifier = taskModel.id.uuidString
                    
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)      
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: taskIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

            let localNotificationDelegate = LocalNotificationDelegate()
            self.center.delegate = localNotificationDelegate
            
            let markAsCompleted = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "MARK_AS_COMPLETED", title: "Mark as Completed", options: .foreground)
            
            let placeholder = "Task"
            let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "Task Actions", actions: [markAsCompleted], intentIdentifiers: [], hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder: placeholder) // // Same Identifier in schedulNotification()
            
            self.center.setNotificationCategories([category])
            
            self.center.add(request)
        }
    }
```

The Notification Delegate

```
internal final class LocalNotificationDelegate: NSObject, ObservableObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        if response.actionIdentifier == "MARK_AS_COMPLETED" {
            // its didn't print the message when I tap the action button
            print("MARK_AS_COMPLETED Tapped")
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Store `localNotificationDelegate` in property, because it is deleted once function returned and cleared in `UNUserNotificationCenter` because it is weak there.

Comment: Thanks "Asperi" its work know, but when I tap the action its should make the action and dismiss the notification, but know it's make the action and open the app.

Comment: I fond how to make an action on notification action button without open the app in the question "Do not open the app when a local notification is clicked in iOS" in the stack over flow, you just need to remove the "option" in the "UNNotificationAction" when create the action button.

Answer (score 2):

my two cents after spending 1 H fighting against SwiftUI.
(Note: documentation is a bit lacking... )

1. without delegate, UserNotifications does not work. (Usually we should use AppDelegate in beloved, old UIKIt... )
2. for App delegate we must use as per:

(Tanks to https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app)

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

3. even so, without "optional" delegation calls it does not work.. so You must implement at least:

   ```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
   ```

now my complete code: (I *DO know* is not always fine, but for beginners will be a matter of copy/paste to make it work.)

I have added some notes and variations to calls.

-- APP --

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct LocalNotificationSwiftUIApp: App {
    
    // tanks to https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    
    // app delegate:
    
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

            // print("Your code here")

            let nc = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            // if You do not set delegate, does not work.
            nc.delegate = self

            return true
        }
        
        
        // called after user has tapped on notification ballon.
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            
            let request = notification.request
            //let content = request.content
            let identifier = request.identifier
            //let title = content.title
            //print(title)
            print( identifier,"\n----\n")
            
        completionHandler([.banner, .list, .badge, .sound])
        } // end of userNotificationCenter

    }
    
}
```

-- ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("SCHEDULE", action: schedule)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: prepareForNotifications)
    }
    
    
    func prepareForNotifications(){

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            
            print("\(granted)")
            if granted {
                // run automatically... on run
                self.schedule()
            }
        }
    } // end of prepareForNotifications
    
    
    
    func schedule()  {
        
        let NOTIFICATION_DELAY  = 5.0             // if repeating, min is 60 secs.
        let NOTIFICATION_ID  = "NOTIFICATION_ID" // note: if repeating, ID must be differr, otherwise IOS will consider only once with this ID

        let USE_INTERVAL = true                 // experiment..

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        
        content.title = "Hello!"
        content.body = "Hello message body"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.badge = 1
        
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                
        if USE_INTERVAL{
            
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(
                timeInterval: NOTIFICATION_DELAY,
                //repeats: true // if true, min 60 secs.
                repeats: false
            )
            
            let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                                     content: content,
                                                     trigger: trigger)
            // Schedule the notification.
            center.add(request)
            
        }else{
            // USE DATE:
            
            let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
            let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate,
                                                        repeats: true)
            
            let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                                     content: content,
                                                     trigger: trigger)
            // Schedule the notification.
            center.add(request)
            
        }
        
    }
        
}
```